# Fuzzy String Matching using R

Tags: r, string

I have column `x` which has a string `ABN-AMRO-NV/SUNTRUST-BK/WACHOVIA` and column `y` which has a string `SunTrust Banks`. As you can see, column `x` has three strings together which are separated by forward slash. So, I would have to split using `strsplit` to separate the string before fuzzy matching. To do fuzzy matching I tried packages such as `stringdist`, `adist`, `agrep` etc. But I have not got good result as I expected.

So, what should be a good way to solve my matching problem?. How can I approach this matching problem to get the good result?. As you can see in the example, `SunTrust Banks` matches with the word `SUNTRUST-BK` which is I am expecting as a result, using fuzzy matching.

Also, just to provide note, my strings in column `x` and column `y` will vary a lot. For example, strings in column `x` will have sometime no forward slash, means only one string.

Thank you all for your help and guidance.

Comment: How good is "Not as good as I expected"? Also, do you always have one match in a small selection? For the example case nearly every simple method should be able to identify the middle option as the best match. (Including the aforementioned `agrep` which uses the levenshtein distance).

Comment: Sorry if it seems vague. What I meant that I tried with varying max. distance using matching packages. The set max. distance worked for few strings but not for the rest. My column `x' is very large and string varies a lot.

Comment: Perhaps you should include typical examples where your approach fails (rather than one where it already succeeds). Especially examples where you feel that it should not need to fail. -- If you are lucky, thinking of these examples may already give you some ideas on how to tackle the problem!

Comment: add `dput` please so It's easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the example below. I just used a random matching method (in this case JaroWinkler).

```
library(stringdist)

fuzzy_select<-function(name_vec,name){
  Filter(function(x) ain(x, name, maxDist=.7, method="jw"), 
         strsplit(name_vec, "/")[[1]])
}

fuzzy_select("ABN-AMRO-NV/SUNTRUST-BK/WACHOVIA", "SunTrust Banks")
```

As you see the `maxDist` has to be quite high in order to find a match between `SUNTRUST-BK` and `SunTrust Banks`. Probably you would like to do some preprocessing before the matching (e.g. convert to lowercase, remove punctuations).